# cannot start jdk 1.8.0_65-b17

Tags: java, java-8

when I try to start the jdk1.8.0_65-b17 in win7, using command like:`javac Test.java`,the java takes more and more physical memory till 99% but it cannot startup.

Does anybody meet this issue before?

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

BTW, it takes nearly one minute to print this version information.

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin>java -Xshare:dump
Allocated shared space: 37879808 bytes at 0x0000000800000000
Loading classes to share ...
Loading classes to share: done.
Rewriting and linking classes ...
Rewriting and linking classes: done
Number of classes 2482
    instance classes   =  2468
    obj array classes  =     6
    type array classes =     8
Calculating fingerprints ... done.
Removing unshareable information ... done.
Shared Lookup Cache Table Buckets = 8216 bytes
Shared Lookup Cache Table Body = 64792 bytes
ro space:   6881424 [ 36.3% of total] out of  16777216 bytes [41.0% used] at 0x0000000800000000
rw space:  10456280 [ 55.2% of total] out of  16777216 bytes [62.3% used] at 0x0000000801000000
md space:   1562448 [  8.3% of total] out of   4194304 bytes [37.3% used] at 0x0000000802000000
mc space:     34053 [  0.2% of total] out of    131072 bytes [26.0% used] at 0x0000000802400000
total   :  18934205 [100.0% of total] out of  37879808 bytes [50.0% used]
An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file.
Unable to create shared archive file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\server\classes.jsa.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to use shared archive.`

Meanwhile, I found lot's of "TBM***.tmp" file in the folder "\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\ext\", about 40G totally, Does anybody familiar about this?[image]

Comment: `javac Test.java`, I have correct my post. I have 8G RAM, 50%used normally,shouldn't be the small amount memory problem.

Comment: Did you try any diagnostic options, e.g. `-verbose` or `-Xdiag`?

Comment: I just did. tried `-Xdiag` nothing logged as before.

Comment: Tried `-verbose`, logging lots of `[Loaded`, but it became extremely slow after `[Loaded java.lang.Void from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\rt.jar]`

Comment: Try to run *once* with `-Xshare:dump` to regenerate the shared class data archive. Then run once again with `-verbose`, the message should change to `[Loaded … from shared objects file]` for most JRE classes (and the startup hopefully become faster for the next runs).

Comment: What does your `Test.java` do? I believe it's more then a print of `Hello world`.

Comment: I tried `javac Test.java -Xshare:dump` nothing logged as before. But when I checked the jdk folder, I found lots of "TBM***.tmp" file in the `jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\ext`, do you know what are they?

Comment: You need to run it as `java -Xshare:dump`. Running it as `javac Test.java -Xshare:dump` should have printed an error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but good to try to unblock you.

- Did you do recent upgrade to jdk-8?
- If yes, can you uninstall the current jdk, restart the machine and install jdk-8? Depending on you machine, choose 64 or 32 bit-based jdk-8.